# Making stopover but luggage to final destination

Tags: air-travel, luggage, luggage-storage, stopovers

I would like to go to Entebbe Airport but make a stop of say 2 weeks in Logos. Will my luggage be flown to my final destination?

Answer (score 17):

You'd ordinarily need to specify the airline and other details (single ticket vs multiple bookings, etc....), but in this case, it's pretty unlikely that any major airline will hold your luggage for you for two weeks in this situation. Airlines are not in the storage business.

Your luggage will be flown to your stopover point, where you'll need to claim it. You can then take it with you or arrange for someone to store it (this may be available at the airport; is "Logos" really "Lagos?") until you check it in for your next flight.

Comment: If you assume the OP had two tickets, one to (sic) Logos, and then Logos to Entebbe, then most large airport baggage claims have a clerk from each airline that collects bags not picked up from a flight and puts them into storage until someone claims them, but I would imagine you would get notified within a day or so, and if you don't pick it up right away I imagine they have a high fee for storage; higher than lockers, etc.

Comment: @MarkStewart That is possible. Lost luggage does have to get stored somewhere while they figure out how to get it to owners (or they eventually declare it unclaimed and sell it off), but I wouldn't want to rely on it, especially with something I cared about, as there's no real guarantee it would work out, I'd get the bags back when I specifically needed them (I've played the "your bag should be in here somewhere" game for hours), or that the left luggage office is a trustworthy place to entrust with my belongings. Abusing the system in this way, there's a decent chance it could go wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I have done what the OP is trying to do, though I was transiting Kuala Lumpur and my stopover was only 29 hours, also I specifically asked the check-in staff to check my bag through to my final destination. I presume my baggage just sat around the baggage handling area until the connecting flight was ready.

I have also had an occasion when I stopped in Los Angeles for 6 days but on that occasion I had to pick up the baggage and use a storage service that advertised at the airport.

I guess it will depend on the country and airline in question.  Best bet would be to ask the airline, probably the most knowledgeable person to ask would be the check-in staff or baggage handlers of your airline.  If not ask them if there is a good storage service near the airport.

Comment: Or phone the airline's customer service number in advance of the flight. By the way, you seem to be writing from the assumption that the asker wants the airline to store their luggage; I'd assume that they actually want to have their luggage while they're at their intermediate destination, rather than having to live on their hand baggage for two weeks! :-)